# In my Mern stack project and I'm signing users with microsoft account in the tenant as well as with personal account but unable to call the graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, msal.js

I'm using @azure/msal-node package for my node js backend for signing in users and getting an access token for calling the m365 graph api. It works for the user inside our tenant but not for personal microsoft accounts. In my Microsoft Entra ID manifest, I changed the signInAudience to: "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount", and it logs in the user successfully with personal accounts as well, but the access token received is short as compared to the access token received for the tenant users. And also the token is not in JWT format, when I copy-paste in jwt.io or jwt.ms it has no user data. And all these things works in the graph explorer fine. And when I copy the access token from graph explorer and paste in our application or POSTMAN, it works, I don't know how.
I want to allow all accounts with linked or associated with microsoft to login to my application.
Thanks!

I tried changing the permissions in the Microsoft Entra ID but nothing works, the token received for microsoft personal accounts is not working.
I've also changed the endpoint to /common. Before it was https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID.
Now, changing it to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common also it is not working, just signing in the user that's it. Unable to fetch logged in user data, unable to call the m365 graph api.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What endpoints are you calling on Graph API? Some endpoints are not supported for personal accounts. An example is teams endpoints. The token will be different and it should not worry you as long as you can call graph /me endpoint for the personal account

Comment: @Danstan, I'm calling the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me endpoint for fetching the logged in user profile/data. And after that I also want to fetch the Calendar Events ( 
CRUD ). I think issue is in receiving the code which we receive in the URL after successfull login. I mentioned it as "grant_type":"authorization_code"